# Duplicated index in MySql table

Tags: mysql, database, indexing

Assume I have a table in MySql database like this:

`Pet
PetId - [bigint]
Name - [varchar(50)]`

And `PetId` column is my Primary key. This means that I have PRIMARY index for PetId column.

And assume I've created another index as UNIQUE for the same `PetId` column like in screenshoot:
[image]

Will MySql actually create another index for `PetId_Uniq` and will there be any performance differences?

I know this is kind of silly to create indexes like that. But I've found such situation in an existing database and I'm curious if this `PetId_Uniq` will end up as a separate index in MySql(which will be an overhead) or will be just ignored(so it's just about clearing up mess in the schema).

Comment: Why don't you try it out and see what happens? Adding indices to a database causes no harm to the data

Comment: How do I profile what indexes are actually created and maintained by MySql?

Comment: Which indices are created is visible in phpMyAdmin or through `SHOW INDEX FROM table`, and which ones are used is visible through `EXPLAIN`

Comment: A `PRIMARY KEY` _is_ (in MySQL) a `UNIQUE KEY`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Both indexes get generated. But [8.3.1 How MySQL Uses Indexes](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/mysql-indexes.html) states:

> If there is a choice between multiple indexes, MySQL normally uses the index that finds the smallest number of rows (the most selective index).

Comment: And there would be a performance impact on inserts/updates because it *does* maintain separate indices.

Comment: Are there any tools that allow to profile such things in database?